# react native map element shows not text why?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I map sizes and want to display which user selected which size. Its work but its not display.

if I console.log this:

```
          <View style={{flex: 1, height: 250}}>
            {
              product.color.map((el, i) => {
                if(el.size.length > 0) {
                  el.size.map(e => {
                    return typeof e !== 'undefined' && console.log(e);
                  })
                }
              })
            }
          </View>
```

Then I get:

```
Object {
  "size": "150",
  "sizeAmount": null,
}
Object {
  "size": "155",
  "sizeAmount": null,
}
```

So now I want to display the checked sizes. I remove the console.log(e) in the above example and add {e.size}.

but I get no errors and no displayed text. Why ? I mean in my console.log I get the results

```
            {
              product.color.map((el, i) => {
                if(el.size.length > 0) {
                  el.size.map(e => {
                    return typeof e !== 'undefined' && <Text style={{color: '#333', fontSize: 24, flex: 1}}>{e.size}</Text>
                  })
                }
              })
            }
```

Comment: You need to return the map result `return el.size.map(e => {`

Answer (score 0):

you were using map on el.size.map() //it will take value 2 because size of el is 2 ,so how map will work on no instead of array or object

```js
 <View style={{flex: 1, height: 250}}>
            {
            product.color.map((el, i) => {
           if(el.size.length > 0) {
            return typeof e !== 'undefined' && <Text style={{color: '#333', 
            fontSize: 24, flex: 1}}> {el.size} </Text>
         }
       
     })
            }
          </View>
```